# Angular, Use short component selector based on the parent component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing a library for the UI components. I created a parent component (using ng-content) that assigns css to the children, and declares that this part of the interface will be built using the library's element components.

I would like to avoid having writing every time a full name with prefix for the child components.

For example I want to build a form component:

```
<dvl-ui-theme theme="basic">
  <dvl-ui-active-form>
    <dvl-ui-input name="input-name">
  </dvl-ui-active-form>
</dvl-ui-theme>
```

I would like to use something like

```
<dvl-ui-theme theme="basic">
  <active-form>
    <input name="input-name">
  </active-form>
</dvl-ui-theme>
```

It will be shorter and much more readable.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

EDIT: To summarize and make it clear - I want to have different selector of the component based on the parent component element.

Normally I would use `<dvl-ui-input>` but since the input is in the form, I would like to use `<input>` and have the same component initialized

Answer (score 0):

The Selector of an angular Component is defined in the `***.component.ts` file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root', // <= here you can change the selector of your component
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

this will look like so in your .html file:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

Be aware that duplicate selectors will cause issues. Also you cannot use plain html tag names as your component selector like: `input`,`div`,`h1`, etc...

Comment: I know but I want it to have different selector based on the parent component that the element is nested in.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. At least there is no ready solution provided by angular.

Comment: To implement some similiar behaviour yourself, you may go with the `ComponentFactoryResolver`. But only a (slightly) better readability is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: I was curious how angular does register new `tags`. With `window.customElements.define(''my-tag-name", CustomElementConstructor)` you can define any custom element. That's probably the better hint than the previous comment.